# I think I wrecked my 2017 Macbook pro. Tried to update SSD but accidentally used SSD with different pin config. Now Macbook won't respond

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, hardware, upgrade

I just bought a used 2017 MBP non-touchbar with a 128Gb SSD.  I ordered an adapter and a 500Gb SSD.  I forgot to check the SSD compatibility with MBP. When I installed the adapter and SSD the MBP wouldn't recognize the new SSD. I removed the SSD and only then noticed the pin config on the new SSD was totally different. I reinstalled the OEM SSD and tried to boot but MBP is totally dead.  I've tried all the key combinations mentioned in the forums to no avail.  I unplugged the battery for several hours to see if it would help but still no life.  My question is do you think I blew out the logic board and will need to have it replaced?  I am sick because this was a new MBP to me.

Comment: From the sound of things, you probably fried the system board.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.